# Re-download music on the same Mac

Tags: itunes

I did buy an album and for some reason a song in this album did not fully downloaded however iTunes thinks it is. So I deleted it and went back to the store to re-download it again. In the store it wrote 'Downloading' next to the song but the song is not getting downloaded. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the song, Restart iTunes, go into the iTunes Store and on the Mainpage under Quicklinks "Purchased". Try to download the song again.